# Constructor function "creates" infinite loop in JS

Tags: javascript

I noticed some weird behavior in constructor functions. This code loops infinitely and I don't know why.

```js
function thing(){
    this.start=function (){console.log(this.msg)};
    this.msg="Starting...";
    setInterval(() => {this.start()},1000)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="new thing()">Create a new thing!</button>
```

I've searched about this but I found nothing that explains this. Please someone help me and answer why this happens.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you are calling `setInterval`, which will loop forever. Is that not what you want?

Comment: You all are right. I haven't noticed my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: What I thought was happening was that when I called the `thing.start()`, it made some kind of recursion and keep setting the interval.

Comment: `start` doesn't call `thing`, so there's no way recursion could happen here.

Comment: Now I know that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you wanted to use `setInterval` not `setTimeout`? The former will call`this.start` every 1 second, while the latter will be called once after 1 second,
Please take a look at the below links explaining both functions:

1. `setInterval`
   https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/setInterval
2. `setTimeout`
   https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/setTimeout

Correct snippet should be:

```js
function thing(){
    this.start=function (){console.log(this.msg)};
    this.msg="Starting...";
    setTimeout(this.start(), 1000)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="new thing()">Create a new thing!</button>
```

Comment: I was actually thinking this as I saw the question, I like this mistake, quite a comical one :)

Answer (score 1):

It does so because `setInterval()` sets up an... You've guessed it! `Interval`, which continues to execute it's contents at the interval you've set (`1000ms` in this example).

`setTimeout()` will delay execution once at the set delay.

Answer (score 1):

Yes setInterval will call after 1 sec so if you want to stop that you need to use clearInterval.

Answer (score 1):

From the [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) documentation:

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
>
> The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.
>
> The ID value returned by setInterval() is used as the parameter for the clearInterval() method.
>
> Tip: 1000 ms = 1 second.
>
> Tip: To execute a function only once, after a specified number of milliseconds, use the setTimeout() method.

So you may want to do:

```js
function thing(){
    this.start=function (){console.log(this.msg)};
    this.msg="Starting...";
    setTimeout(() => {this.start()}, 1000)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="new thing()">Create a new thing!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is actually supposed to start an interval (timed loop).

Also, you are executing the function rather than binding it :) Common mistake.

```
onclick="new thing()"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Your code can be done much simpler:

```
const start = () => setTimeout( () => console.log(200), 1000)

<button onclick="start">Start!</button>
```

In most cases, you will not need objects in JS. Functions as first-class objects are a very powerful feature of JS.